# Loading template dynamically inside ng-repeat

Tags: templates, dynamic, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my requirement.

```
<div ng-repeat="inv in invitations">
   <div ng-click="ShowDetails()">{{inv.Id}}<div>
   <div>My Details: LoadTemplate(details.html)</div> //template will load dynamically                                if i click id       
</div>
```

details.html

```
<div>
  {{inv.Name}} {{inv.Email}}
</div>
```

Result will be like:

```
1
My Details ilias shi@g.com
2
My Details ilias2 shi3@g.com
```

Here my details will be shown if i click on id(1, 2). I do not want to load each details inside ng-click. Instead want to fetch it from server once i click on id.

Comment: You can use `ng-include` to load the template from server or template.

Comment: you can use ng-include as chandermani said, but this screams of directive to me, where you can define the templateUrl.